# MySql multi delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just trying to delete a member, but he's still in my table because he's used by other tables. So, I'm trying to delete all the `FK` using it. But, this code doesn't work!

```
`DELETE FROM t_membre USING t_membre RIGHT JOIN t_commande_has_t_membre RIGHT JOIN t_fusil RIGHT JOIN t_rapport_de_tir 
ON T_Membre_PK_Membre=(SELECT T_Membre_PK_Membre FROM t_commande_has_t_membre WHERE T_Membre_PK_Membre = '2') ON 
T_Membre_PK_Membre = (SELECT T_Membre_PK_Membre FROM t_fusil WHERE T_Membre_PK_Membre='2') ON
T_Membre_PK_Membre = (SELECT T_Membre_PK_Membre FROM t_rapport_de_tir WHERE T_Membre_PK_Membre='2')AND
PK_Membre = (SELECT PK_Membre FROM t_membre WHERE PK_Membre='2');`
```

Thank you for everything!

Comment: You have to add from which tables you want to delete: `DELETE a, b FROM ...`

Comment: But, if i'm using FROM..USING ? Why should I add a table between DELETE and FROM?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using INNODB, check your [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could use cascade delete for your task

Comment: Please expand your answer to be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

use

> ON DELETE CASCADE

to delete from multiple tables